# Can dig make a secure zone transfer(axfr) using a Transfer Auth Code (EPP)

Tags: dns, authentication, dig

My domain name registrar (name.com) provides a `Transfer Auth Code` to secure DNS zone transfers.

the `Transfer Auth Code` is also known as AuthInfo Code, AuthInfo Code, EPP, Transfer Key, or Transfer Secret

Does `dig` have an option to make a zone transfer (axfr) witch such a code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. EPP codes are specific to some registries for controlling ownership if a domain. At most it can facilitate - indirectly -  defining what nameservers are authorative so they are added into the tld zone. - which is NOT the zone for the domain.

An axfr request is done against the authorative nameserver (which is not the tld nameserver).

The mechanisms and APIs here are entirely different and for different non-overlapping purposes.

Comment: It's probably worth noting that axfr 's are not even always possible, and depend on the nameserver and it's config.